# Why is CS8983 "A 'struct' with field initializers must include an explicitly declared constructor" seen when using C#10?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, c#-10.0

```
public record struct Results
{
    public int Id=0;
    public List<(int, string)> Items=new();
    public string ErrorMsg="";
}
```

This works fine in .Net Fiddle against ‍`.Net 6` (https://dotnetfiddle.net/yC5B7G) but in `VS2022` a `C# 10/.Net 6` project generates `CS8983`.
[image]
[image]

This surely is valid since [the docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#limitations-with-the-design-of-a-structure-type):

> - Prior to C# 11, a constructor of a structure type must initialize all    instance fields of the type.
> - Prior to C# 10, you can't declare a    parameterless constructor.
> - Prior to C# 10, you can't initialize an    instance field or property at its declaration.

Could this be a bug in VS2022 or are their project settings or cases why this is correct behaviour?

Comment: Looks like it's working as-specified in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/parameterless-struct-constructors: "An error is reported if a struct has field initializers and no declared instance constructors since the field initializers will not be run."

Comment: @JonSkeet then how is my MRE working - I copy that exact `struct` between VS2022 and .NetFiddle? I also found another question from someone who seemingly has it working - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69895817/struct-parameterless-constructor-and-field-initializers-in-c-sharp-10

Comment: My *guess* is that allowing it was a bug which has now been fixed in the compiler - and that dotnetfiddle is using an older compiler version. (Or at least a "change in behavior" if not a bug fix - the spec may have changed around when a parameterless constructor is synthesized, as noted in the comment thread in that question.)

Comment: .Net Fiddle uses preview language version, see `#error version`.

Comment: As per shingo's comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/R0GFFB